Movie with a scene where a female reporter is observing a robot patrol of a Middle Eastern town
I'm trying to identify this movie with a scene where a female reporter is observing a robot patrol of a Middle Eastern town. The patrol of robots is checking IDs with facial recognition. There's some setup where a young boy is trying to join an attack on the robots.
I just have this scene in my head and can't remember what movie it's from.

It is from the 2014 remake of Robocop.
The scene you are describing is early in the movie.
Plot details on Wikipedia:

In 2028, multinational conglomerate OmniCorp revolutionizes warfare
with the introduction of robotic peacekeepers capable of maintaining
law and order in hot spots such as Vietnam, Iraq, Afghanistan, and
Iran.

The name of the female reporter in the movie is Kelly Perkins and she is reporting from Tehran:
Female reporter
Here is the reporter with her cameraman in the street of the town with the robots in the background:
Reporter and her cameraman
Here are the robots patrolling the streets of the town:
Robots patrolling
Here is one of the robots:
Robot
And here is one of the robots making a facial recognition of a woman:
Facial recognition
Here is the boy who also wants to attack the robots:
Boy ready to attack robot
Trailer:



I couldn't find a relevant clip, but at 0:07 and 2:04 in the trailer above  there are short glimpses at the patrolling robots:

